# Nothing under "installed" when adding new item in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add a new C/C++ file item in Visual Studio 2013. However, when I clicked "add new item", there's absolutely nothing under "installed". I'm looking for `Visual C++ > C++` under installed.. What could be wrong?

Is there anything I should be installing? 
Under "Online", I only see `templates>visual c#`.

Thanks for any help, Google is returning nothing for this.

Comment: What version of VS are you running ?

Comment: I'm running VS Express for Desktop 2013.

Comment: What project type are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Win32 Console Application, from `Visual C++>Win32>Win32 Console Application`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop installation.  They forgot to change a registry key to reflect the different directory structure for the express installation compared to the full software.

It is listed in the Workarounds tab and pasted here for reference (originally from Microsoft Connect, which was retired).  Works like a charm.

> ...update TemplatesDir location in registry. The key to update is given below.
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0_Config\Projects{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC943}\AddItemTemplates\TemplateDirs{F1C25864-3097-11D2-A5C5-00C04F7968B4}/1]
>
> "TemplatesDir"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\VCProjectItems_WDExpress"

Comment: Great find, though I would suggest you put the actual Microsoft  Connect URL in your answer instead of the bitly link. Some people might be reticent to click on it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to revert back to an installation VS 2012 due to time constraints so I cannot test it, but I believe your answer!