# I can't add new item on Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Every time I want to add new C++ item on Visual Studio 2013 RC, I get a blank screen like this one [image]
How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to repair your installation? What type of project did you create?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i created an empty windows console application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nothing under "installed" when adding new item in VS 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259707/nothing-under-installed-when-adding-new-item-in-vs-2013)

Comment: Duplicate only if we are talking about Visual Desktop Express, doesn't happen with other versions. @user2798694 What version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted directly from the workaround given [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800202/visual-studio-2013-express-rc-no-items-found-in-the-add-new-item-dialog)

> Thank you for reporting this issue to us. We have identified the issue and have fixed this for the next public release of Visual Studio Desktop Express.
>   In the mean time to work around this issue you can update TemplatesDir location in registry. The key to update is given below.
>
> `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0_Config\Projects\{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC943}\AddItemTemplates\TemplateDirs\{F1C25864-3097-11D2-A5C5-00C04F7968B4}\/1]`
>
> `"TemplatesDir"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\\\VC\\VCProjectItems_WDExpress"`

I had the same problem and it worked for me