# VS Express RC 2013 - How can I update the registry keys?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Recently I stumbled upon an issue with VS:

[Nothing under "installed" when adding new item in VS 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259707/nothing-under-installed-when-adding-new-item-in-vs-2013)

Looking at this question that Microsoft personally responded to I got a way to work around the error:

> Thank you for reporting this issue to us. We have identified the issue
>   and have fixed this for the next public release of Visual Studio
>   Desktop Express. In the mean time to work around this issue you can
>   update TemplatesDir location in registry. The key to update is given
>   below.
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0_Config\Projects{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC943}\AddItemTemplates\TemplateDirs{F1C25864-3097-11D2-A5C5-00C04F7968B4}/1]
>
> "TemplatesDir"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\\VC\VCProjectItems_WDExpress"
>
> Thanks, Vaijanath A VC++ Team

This is the "TemplatesDir", yet I don't know where to change the key.

[image]

Now I dont know how to follow Microsofts instructions.  Its asking me to 'update TemplatesDir location in registry and gives me a key [HKEY_CURRENT.....]

**Can you please redefine this answer provided by Microsoft and tell me what to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the registry. To do this run `regedit.exe`. This will open the registry editor. Find the key

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0_Config\Projects{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC943}\AddItemTemplates\TemplateDirs{F1C25864-3097-11D2-A5C5-00C04F7968B4}/1]
```

And change its value to

```
"TemplatesDir"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\VCProjectItems_WDExpress"
```

Save and restart your machine.

Comment: I'm assuming the quotes are necessary?

Comment: @BDillan - I believe so. But if doesn't work that way you can remove it afterwards.

Comment: It worked - it was stupid though asking if I should include the quotes xD

Comment: @BDillan - No question is stupid as the (true) cliche goes. Glad things worked out for you :)